# I'm trying to merge all the excel spreadsheet into one Master spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to write an Excel Macro that will traverse through all the folders in the directory, and merge multiple excel spreadsheet into one. All the excel spreadsheet have the same format.

I'm able to traverse through all the folders in the directory but I keep getting errors when I try to merge the excel spreadsheet together.

This is the error message I got:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Excel cannot insert the sheets into the destination workbook, because
>   it contains fewer rows and columns than the source workbook. To move
>   or copy the data to the destination workbook, you can select the data,
>   and then use the Copy and Paste commands to insert it into the sheets
>   of another workbook.

This is what I have done so far:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FileListingAllFolder()

Dim pPath As String
Dim FlNm As Variant
Dim ListFNm As New Collection ' create a collection of filenames

Dim OWb As Workbook
Dim ShtCnt As Integer
Dim Sht As Integer

Dim MWb As Workbook
Dim MWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

' Open folder selection
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    pPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Create master workbook with single sheets
Set MWb = Workbooks.Add(1)
MWb.Sheets(1).Name = "Result"
Set MWs = MWb.Sheets("Result")

' Filling a collection of filenames (search Excel files including subdirectories)
Call FlSrch(ListFNm, pPath, "*Issues.xls*", True)


' Print list to immediate debug window and as a message window
For Each FlNm In ListFNm ' cycle for list(collection) processing

    'Start Processing here
    Set OWb = Workbooks.Open(FlNm)
    ShtCnt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For Sht = 1 To ShtCnt
        Sheets(Sht).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sht
    OWb.Close False
Next FlNm

' Print to immediate debug window and message if no file was found
If ListFNm.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No file was found !"
    MsgBox "No file was found !"
    MWb.Close False
    End
End If

MWb.Activate
MWs.Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

End

NextCode:
MsgBox "You Click Cancel, and no folder selected!"

End Sub

Private Sub FlSrch(pFnd As Collection, pPath As String, pMask As String, pSbDir As Boolean)

Dim flDir As String
Dim CldItm As Variant
Dim sCldItm As New Collection

' Add backslash at the end of path if not present
pPath = Trim(pPath)

If Right(pPath, 1) <> "\" Then pPath = pPath & "\"

' Searching files accordant with mask
flDir = Dir(pPath & pMask)
    Do While flDir <> ""
        pFnd.Add pPath & flDir 'add file name to list(collection)
        flDir = Dir ' next file
    Loop

' Procedure exiting if searching in subdirectories isn't enabled
If Not pSbDir Then Exit Sub

' Searching for subdirectories in path
flDir = Dir(pPath & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While flDir <> ""
    ' Do not search Scheduling folder
        If flDir <> "Scheduling" Then
            ' Add subdirectory to local list(collection) of subdirectories in path
            If flDir <> "." And flDir <> ".." Then If ((GetAttr(pPath & flDir) And _
            vbDirectory) = 16) Then sCldItm.Add pPath & flDir
        End If
        flDir = Dir 'next file
    Loop

' Subdirectories list(collection) processing
For Each CldItm In sCldItm
    Call FlSrch(pFnd, CStr(CldItm), pMask, pSbDir) ' Recursive procedure call
Next

End Sub
```

I think this is the part that causes the problem.

```
For Each FlNm In ListFNm ' cycle for list(collection) processing

        'Start Processing here
        Set OWb = Workbooks.Open(FlNm)
        ShtCnt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        For Sht = 1 To ShtCnt
            Sheets(Sht).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sht
        OWb.Close False
    Next FlNm
```

I have been trying to mess with this code for two days now. I'm not too sure where I did it wrong.  :(

Comment: Are you working with a mixture of Excel 2003 (or earlier) and 2007 ? Seems like all your workbooks don't have sheets of the same size. Could also be caused by Excel 2007 workbooks saved in compatability mode.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbu/archive/2010/07/29/excel-cannot-insert-the-sheets-into-the-destination-workbook-because-it-contains-fewer-rows-and-columns.aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams No I'm working with Excel 2007 only. All my workbook have total of 18 columns and rows are different.

Comment: Before you try copying each sheet add `Debug.Print Sheets(Sht).Rows.Count`. Then compare that with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count`

Comment: @yyc2001: Tim is right :) The mere fact that you are using `"*Issues.xls*"` in code will pickup `.xls` files as well :)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. I will definitely try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have acess to vb.net I would urge you to use that in combination with Excel-Interop.
I have tried the same thing as you do know - basically, it never worked 100% satisfactory with pure VBA. The combination of Vb.net and interop worked like a charm.

Comment: Would be nice if you could expand this answer and provide an example of such code?